# fetch API method patch in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, fetch-api

i request method patch in php but, There was a problem Undefined index variable from use **$_POST** and **$_GET**

**javascript**

```
 document.getElementById("editevent").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = document.querySelector("#editevent");
    const data = new FormData();
    for (const p of new FormData(form)) {
      data.append(p[0], p[1]);
    }
  
    fetch(`../mufevent/class/event.php/${id}`, {
     
      method: "PATCH",
      body: data,
    
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        alert(response);
      
      });
```

**to: file.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PATCH") {
   
    echo $_POST['date'];
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `$_REQUEST` variable?

Comment: PHP doesn't populate those variables for PATCH requests. You need to get the raw request body and parse it yourself. You can see in the link above how to get that data.